# How to retrieve data from a related table by using ArcGIS JavaScript API 4.1?

Tags: arcgis-server, layers, features, table, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a feature layer and a related table. I want retrieve information from the related table and show them.

Which API is referenced when using ArcGIS JavaScript API 4.1.?

Answer (score 2):

As of now, there isn't a direct API functionality in ArcGIS JavaScript 4.1 that you can use to retrieve a related table, not yet at least, it is **coming soon** according to Esri. The release from API 3.18 to 4.1 has left some functionality still to be made available.

[image]

[image]

Description of FeatureTable from API 3.18 [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featuretable-amd.html)

You can check out the functionality matrix for more information between the API 3.18 and 4.1 [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/functionality-matrix/index.html)